# Set child element width to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a parent div and inside that child element will be table.

I'm hidding some columns in the table through CSS to avoid inline-style.

So how can I reflect the width to parent div after hiding the column of table...

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#yourtableid").width();
```

returns the computed pixel width of the table element with id yourtableid.

```
$("#yourdivid").width ( $("#yourtableid").width() );
```

will set the parent div width.

See

[CSS/width](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/width)

Comment: due to some padding margin i'm getting little more value than wat table appears.

so div is little bigger than table...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll need to use jQuery [`innerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) method (calculates elements width with padding without calculating border width) and [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) (calculates elements width with padding and border size included).

If you supply optional boolean argument to `outerWidth()` (eg : `outerWidth(true)`),  it'll include also size of margins.

So in this case your code will be

```
$("#yourdivid").width($("#yourtableid").innerWidth());
```